# Ubuntu 16 sed not working with parenthesis

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed

Oh, I can't get past this SED regex. This line **"entrytimestamp" : ISODate("2020-09-09T16:07:34.526Z")** in the first record should also be transformed but since it does not have a comma after the closing parenthesis it is not. Simply I want to remove *"ISODate("* and the closing parenthesis *")"*. But it should not matter if is it the last element or not. I have double/triple checked the REGEX but I am missing something. Does anybody have any idea?

```
root@# cat inar.json
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f58fdc632e4de001621c1ca"),
                "USER" : null,
                "entrytimestamp" : ISODate("2020-09-09T16:07:34.526Z")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f590118c205630016dcafb4"),
                "entrytimestamp" : ISODate("2020-09-09T16:21:44.346Z"),
                "USER" : null
        }
]
```

```
sed -E "s/(.+\"entrytimestamp\"\s:\s)ISODate\((\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1,3}Z\")\)(.+)/\1\2\3/" inar.json
```

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f58fdc632e4de001621c1ca"),
                "USER" : null,
                "entrytimestamp" : ISODate("2020-09-09T16:07:34.526Z")
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f590118c205630016dcafb4"),
                "entrytimestamp" : "2020-09-09T16:21:44.346Z",
                "USER" : null
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/("entrytimestamp" *: *)ISODate\(([^)]+)\)/\1\2/' file
```

```
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f58fdc632e4de001621c1ca"),
                "USER" : null,
                "entrytimestamp" : "2020-09-09T16:07:34.526Z"
        },
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5f590118c205630016dcafb4"),
                "entrytimestamp" : "2020-09-09T16:21:44.346Z",
                "USER" : null
        }
]
```

**Command Details**

- `("entrytimestamp" *: *)`: Match starting `"entrytimestamp" :` part with optional spaces around `:`. Capture this part in group #1
- `ISODate\(`: Match `ISODate(`
- `([^)]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `)`. Capture this part in group #2
- `\)`: Match closing `)`

- `/\1\2`: Put back-references #1 and #2 back in substitution

Comment: this definitely works, thank you. I just don't understand why my regex didnt. If anyone knows why please show me the light.

Comment: Using your regex you may try: `sed -E 's/(.*"entrytimestamp" *: *)ISODate\(("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1,3}Z")\)(.*)/\1\2\3/' file`

Comment: Ok, I see so it has to do with the greediness of the Plus sign vs the Star sign. I am reading on the gnu sed site but can really see the "why". But thanks for pointing me in the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match the first line you intend to match because of the last `(.+)` that matches **at least one or more characters**. As there is only a `)` at the end and nothing else to match, the pattern fails.

Use `(.*)` to match any **zero or more characters**:

```
sed -E "s/(.+\"entrytimestamp\"\s:\s)ISODate\((\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1,3}Z\")\)(.*)/\1\2\3/" inar.json
```

[This is how the expression works](https://regex101.com/r/q26qXE/1/).